# How to hide the default fragment actionBar create our own actionBar in android & kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-architecture-navigation

I have an android app with bottom navigation containing 3 fragments and all have their own actionBar by default. I want to hide all the default actionBar of three fragments and create my own actionbar with many options. I am using Kotlin.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

```
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf( R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_messages, R.id.navigation_profile)) 
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

Just remove the above two lines from the main activity and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the style of the app. Go to `values/styles.xml`, edit the value of `AppTheme` as **NoActionBar**. Then to create your own AppBar in each fragments, just use AppBarLayout in your Xml. For instance:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
       ...
 </style>
```

Comment: Yes I tried that before but all the action bar is connected to the bottom navigation menu where the default action bar is shown for each fragment. After I do that my app crashes and I think here I am getting error. Sharing code in the next comment

Comment: override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
      
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_messages, R.id.navigation_profile))

        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

Answer (score 0):

Heres a quick solution.

You find styles.xml and you change the base application theme to "Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" as shown below.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

and define custom layout of action bar in xml

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ActionBar is Activities property, not fragments. If you want a custom action bar follow this link, https://myandroid.site/custom-toolbar-with-style-in-kotlin-design-colorful-toolbar/

**or**

You can have the default ActionBar in Activity & create your own layout that look like an action bar.

Hide Action Bar(Below code should be inside Activity):

```
if (supportActionBar != null)
    supportActionBar?.hide()
```

Comment: I think you don't know about connecting the action bar to the fragments.

Comment: ActionBar/ToolBar is Activity property. you don't connect ActionBar to fragment, you just access it in fragment by getActivity() or requireActivity() mehods.